# Обновление окна WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Начал разбираться в WPF, и сразу столкнулся с такой проблемой: в коде есть переменная, которую я постоянно меняю. Она отображается в форме в Label. Но при изменении ее в коде в форме она не меняется. Как это вообще реализуется? У меня эта переменная изменяется в отдельном фоновом потоке, и нужно, чтобы на экране она тоже обновлялась.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для начала, вам нужно, чтобы переменная, которую вы отображаете на экране, была частью `DataContext`. Например, вы кладёте её в класс, и присваиваете `DataContext`'у его экземпляр:

```
class VM
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

```
VM vm = new VM();
```

```
window.DataContext = vm;
```

Теперь можно привязаться к вашему свойству:

```xaml
<Label Content="{Binding Message}"/>
```

Но это не всё. Для того, чтобы окно увидело *изменения* переменной, вы должны реализовать интерфейс `INotifyPropertyChanged`:

```
class VM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    string message;
    public string Message
    {
        get { return message; }
        set { if (message != value) { message = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); } }
    }

    void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Но и это ещё не всё. Теперь чтобы всё работало правильно, вам нужно устанавливать значение VM-свойства **только в главном потоке**. Как это делать — зависит от выбранных вами инструментальных средств.
Например, вы можете использовать `BeginInvoke` в вашем рабочем потоке. Или выполнять вычисления в фоне при помощи техники async/await.

Comment: Благодарю, почти разобрался.

Comment: > Например, вы можете использовать BeginInvoke в вашем рабочем потоке. Это как? Ну вот допустим мы не используем команды, тогда мы можем вызвать нужный метод VM из window, например так `((VM)DataContext).МойМетод;` А зачем нужен `BeginInvoke`? Пример дайте, пожалуйста.

Comment: @Bulson: Ну, ТС говорит, что у него переменная меняется в фоновом потоке. Значит, ему вместо `vm.Message = newValue` нужно писать `dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => vm.Message = newValue));` или там `dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => vm.Message = newValue)`

Comment: @Ghoul: Не за что!